# Get environment variables from a .sh script and use them in my Python script

Tags: python, bash, shell

This is what I want to do.

I have a A.sh script which contains environment variables where they are exported (for example `export AEnv==1234`).

Then I have B.sh which calls A.sh:

```
SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
ROOT_DIR="$SCRIPT_DIR/.."

. ${SCRIPT_DIR}/A.sh
```

Then I have a .bat script where I execute the B.sh. Below it I execute my Python script. In my Python script I am looking for the environment variable `AEnv`. But it gives me the following error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 425, in __getitem__
return self.data[key.upper()]
KeyError: 'AEnv'
```

I am using `os.environ['AEnv']`

As I have understood is when B.sh has finished the environment variables does not exist anymore and therefore the failure.

What am I missing?

Comment: That is true. Executing scripts in a simple manner creates a new shell and therefore the env vars are not retained. Please post your code so that we can see how you're calling the script. Also, how exactly are you running `sh` inside `bat`?

Comment: @nir0s Can't post the code sorry. The way I am calling the .sh file in my bat is by writing B.sh

Comment: Is your Python script also started by the .bat file, or before or after? With only A.sh and B.sh the best we can do is suggesting to write the environment in a temporary properties file and read them with Python. Or do you have more scripts you did not tell us about?

Comment: You need to run Python from the shell that manipulates the environment or one of its child processes.

Comment: @WalterA My python script is also started by the .bat script. Nope A.sh and B.sh ,.bat and python is the only scripts I have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by *bat script*, but in any case, you have to deal with two problems:

(1) While you, basically, can name the environment variables in any way you like, you should use UPPER CASE letters only, to avoid portability issues. That is, your environment variable should be named AENV.

(2) As you correctly recognized, you can not "transport" an environment variable from one process to another one, unless the other process is a child process of the process which sets the environment variable. Hence you need to store the value somewhere else. The following three possibilities are a common way to do it:

- The process which defines the value of the environment variables could output name and value to stdout. The calling script catches the output and sets the variables in its own environment. When the Python script is called, the variable will be there.
- The generating script writes the value of the environment variable to a file and the Python program fetches it from the file.
- "Continuation passing style": The master script does **not** call A.sh **and** the Python program, but only A.sh, and passes the invocation line of the Python process to A.sh (either as a parameter or via the environment). A.sh sets the environment, invokes the Python program, and passes the exit code of the Python program back to the caller.

Comment: I will try to write the parameters to a file and then call that file from my python script

Answer (score 0):

Change `export AEnv==1234` into `export AEnv=1234`.
The `bat-file` will never know the environ settings from A.sh.
Try to call your Python from `B.sh` :

```
SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
ROOT_DIR="$SCRIPT_DIR/.."

. ${SCRIPT_DIR}/A.sh

echo "After calling A.sh: AEnv=${AEnv}"

python C/Python27/lib/os.py
```