# Python script to execute source bash script and get environment variables

Tags: python, bash

I need to execute a bash script with source inside my python script. I want to set a environment variable in my shell. At the moment I execute my bash script as follow

```
subprocess.call("source ./script.sh %s %s %s %s" % ("account_id", "bro", "input.csv", "s"), shell=True)
```

The bash script "script.sh" exports a env variable. but I know subprocess wouldn't help.
Is there any other way then please helpout

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? set an env. variable ? as soon as your script ends the variable isn't exported anymore. Just use `os.putenv` or `os.environ` dict

Comment: I need the exported variable from the bash script, which is called from my python script

Comment: so you want the bash script to export a variable that will propagate to the python script? not possible without the python script collaborating more

Comment: You could spawn a shell from the python program. But you cannot modify the environment inside the shell which is executing the python program.

Comment: Correct answer for this question in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794512/get-environment-variables-from-a-sh-script-and-use-them-in-my-python-script)